# How to add multiline in indicatorView?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In indicator View there is only one line to show indicators how I can wrap to next line if indicator count is more?

```
   <IndicatorView x:Name="indicatorView"
                   IndicatorsShape="Circle"
                   IndicatorColor="LightGray"
                   SelectedIndicatorColor="DarkGray"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   Margin="40,100,0,40"
                   MinimumHeightRequest="100"
                   />
```

Comment: Wrap indicators is meaningless? How about set `MaximumVisible` or [this](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13653) might help.

Comment: @shaw Thanks for reply. The requirement is to have multiline indicator..MaximumVisible won't work for this behaviour.

Comment: @nitu Search some info, but can not find any way to do, maybe you can create new feature on [Xamarin.forms gtihub](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues)